# UIAlertView seems to freeze application when uploading data to Parse.com

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, uialertview, ibaction

Hello I am using parse to help with the backend of my iOS app and I created a button that will save my text in my textfields and upload it to the cloud when I click a button.

The code for the button and the alert that pops up is as follows

```
- (IBAction)savebutton:(id)sender {
// Create PFObject with recipe information
PFObject *recipe = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GolfTimes"];
[recipe setObject:_nameTextField.text forKey:@"Name"];
[recipe setObject:_prepTimeTextField.text forKey:@"MemberNumber"];

[recipe setObject:_NumberOfGolfers.text forKey:@"NumberOfGolfers"];

[recipe setObject:_RequestedTime.text forKey:@"RequestedTime"];


NSArray *ingredients = [_ingredientsTextField.text componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
[recipe setObject:ingredients forKey:@"Telephone"];

// Show progress
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Sending...";
[hud show:YES];

// Upload recipe to Parse
[recipe saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    [hud hide:NO];

    if (!error) {
        // Show success message
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Request Sent" message:@"We will get back to you with confirmation." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

        // Notify table view to reload the recipes from Parse cloud
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshTable" object:self];

        // Dismiss the controller
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload Failure" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }

}];}
```

Although the data does send properly and the view controller does close as I made it do, the Alert seems to freeze the app and I cannot click the "Ok" most of the time. When I do click the "OK" button the app simulator shuts down.

Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to dispatch the `UIAlertView` to the main thread like so when you want to show them: **EDIT: You can't have the delegate of the `UIAlertView` be on the `UIViewController` you just dismissed! That's why it's crashing; setting the delegate to: nil should fix that.**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Request Sent" message:@"We will get back to you with confirmation." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];   

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshTable" object:self];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: Yep changing the delegate to nil fixed the problem. Thanks so much @troop231